# use of class with namespace error

Tags: php, oop

in api.php i use severall classes, with autoloaders. in include them like this

```
use \protoware\cms\Account as Account;
use \protoware\cms\Content as Content;
use protoware\cms\Count as Count;
include __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Local this works fine, when i upload it on a server i get this

```
Europe/Brussels] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'protoware\cms\Content' not found in /data/vhosts/achielvolckaert.be/wwwroot/api.php:97
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /data/vhosts/achielvolckaert.be/wwwroot/api.php on line 97
```

line 97 is the first line where i open a connection:

```
$content = new protoware\cms\Content();
                $data = $content->get_content('medisch');
```

I have 0 clue how to fix this, i updated autloader, checked if all files were uploaded...

Comment: Try putting a `\` before protoware.

Comment: Try like this `$content = new \protoware\cms\Content();`

Comment: If you're using a use you can just do `$content = new Content();`

Comment: also use statements don't need the leading \

Comment: What they all said, but when using some class, if the class name is the name you want to use, then you don't need to include "as xxx". So `use protoware\cms\Content as Content;` can just be `use protoware\cms\Content;`

Comment: Can you share folder structure

Comment: He's gone AWOL lol

Answer (score -1):

Try add a \ before class name, like `$content = new \protoware\cms\Content();` or just `$content = new Content()` since you have a use statement.

If this class is a dependency, check if its correctly installed (inside your vendor folder, i.e.). Maybe run `composer install`?